# Merge Request Contains Merge Conflicts

Tags: merge, gitlab, merge-conflict-resolution

I made a merge request to merge my current branch with the master branch but the branches seem to be unable to merge giving me the following notification.

[image]

When I click the "Merge locally" button I'm given a series of commands I'm meant to execute but I'm not exactly sure where or how I'm supposed to execute them, are they meant to work in CMD or something else?  Just for context I've been doing all my commits and what not through Visual Studio so I'm not fimilar with these commands.

So how am I supposed to follow GitLab's recommended steps for resolving a merge conflict or is there any other way to solve a merge conflict that might be more, "my speed"?

Comment: You have to enter those commands in a terminal. For Windows you could get something like https://git-for-windows.github.io/ I'm not a Windows guy though... Visual Studio probably provides a way to merge branches and resolve conflicts too

Comment: @Jawad Is CMD not a terminal of sorts, should it work?  I also notice your link gives three options any idea which one to use?  As far as solving the issue through Visual Studio I haven't found anything and when you search online everyone likes to talk about the commands I don't know how to use.

Comment: The problem with CMD is that git doesn't come shipped with it so you still have to install it somehow

Comment: @Jawad Ah okay, I'll do that.  Thanks.